# Postfix EHLO Banner

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta

I have a peculiar problem with Postfix 3.1.0:

When a connecting client issues EHLO, the server responds with a line that contains its internal hostname, instead of the expected value of the **smtpd_banner** parameter.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mxdomain.com ESMTP
EHLO a.aa
250-localhost.name.internal
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41943040
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
```

In the above example

- the **mxdomain.com ESMTP** has been configured using **smtpd_banner = mxdomain.com ESMTP** in main.cf.
- The **localhost.name.internal** text, I would like to have to be the same mxdomain.com text. The current value comes from **$myhostname**

How do I make the second banner contain mxdomain.com, or can it be removed somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I make the second banner contain mxdomain.com, or can it be removed somehow?

Don't set smtpd_banner, set myhostname instead e.g.:

myhostnasme = mx.domain.com